# MatLAB loading image and showing it correctly

Tags: matlab, imshow

I am trying to load an image and show it in MATLAB. It used to work on my other computer a while ago but on this computer the picture looks completely wrong and I am not sure why.

Thanks for all the help in advance.

This is the image I am loading:
[https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13524574/(1).png](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13524574/%281%29.png)

This is how MatLAB shows it: 
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13524574/WrongImage.png

Here is my code:

```
function main()

    workingDir = 'E:\MASTERS\MatLAB\FullVideo_R_OF_HOF\Images';
    S4A = zeros(360,640,3,256);

    %getting 256 frames of the images
    for ii = 1:256 
        S4A(:,:,:,ii)  = imread(fullfile(workingDir,'S4A',strcat('(',int2str(ii),').png')));
    end

    %showing first frame only
    imshow(S4A(:,:,:,1));

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what's going on in there with all those indices but I think I may be able to offer an alternative. Check out the third paragraph of the documentation, [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imread.html), for return value information. I suggest using a cell array for clarity.

```
function main()

    workingDir = 'E:\MASTERS\MatLAB\FullVideo_R_OF_HOF\Images';
    S4A = zeros(360,640,3,256);

    %getting 256 frames of the images
    for ii = 1:256 
        A{ii}  = imread(fullfile(workingDir,'S4A',strcat('(',int2str(ii),').png')));
    end

    %showing first frame only
    imshow(A{1});

end
```

Comment: Wonderful! It's also a slightly more robust way to store and access data. The documentation is [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html). Also, I see you're new, welcome! If this is what you're looking for, you can click the check next to the question to accept my answer. Thanks!